# Publish button for logged in and logged out users

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi i'm using Osclass script and have a problem with the publish button on my item post page!

[See image publish button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Adg.png)

Listing Location: The publish button needs to hide for the not registered users and appears for the registered users.

How do i change this code to hide when logged out??

```
<?php if(!osc_is_web_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
```

Publisher Information: publish button needs to appears for not registered users and hide for the registered users. For this i use this code and looks like this works great!

```
<?php if(!osc_is_web_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<fieldset>
  <h2>
     <strong><?php _e("Publisher Information", 'ctg_housing'); ?></strong>
  </h2>
  <div class="item-post-user-name item-post-columns">
    <label class="control-label" for="contactName">
      <span class="required_fields">*</span>
      <?php _e('Name', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
    </label>
    <?php ItemForm::contact_name_text(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="item-post-user-email item-post-columns">
    <label class="control-label" for="contactEmail">
      <span class="required_fields">*</span>
      <?php _e('E-mail', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
    </label>
    <?php ItemForm::contact_email_text(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="submit-button" class="item-post-button text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="small button_radius">
      <?php if($edit) { _e("Update Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } else { _e("Publish Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } ?>
    </button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<?php  } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved here the answer!

```html
        <?php if( osc_is_web_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <fieldset>
          <h2>
            <strong><?php _e('Listing Location', 'ctg_housing'); ?></strong>
          </h2>
          <?php $aCountries = Country::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
          <?php $TwoCountry = false ; if(count($aCountries) > 1 ) { $TwoCountry = true ; ?>
          <div class="item-post-country">
            <label class="control-label" for="country">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Country', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::country_select(osc_get_countries()); ?>
          </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="countryId" id="countryId" value="<?php echo ctg_country_id(); ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="item-post-province">
            <label class="control-label" for="region">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Province', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions()); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="item-post-region">
            <label class="control-label" for="city">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Region', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::city_select(osc_get_cities()); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div id="submit-button" class="item-post-button text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="small button_radius">
              <?php if($edit) { _e("Update Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } else { _e("Publish Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } ?>
            </button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <fieldset>
          <h2>
            <strong><?php _e('Listing Location', 'ctg_housing'); ?></strong>
          </h2>
          <?php $aCountries = Country::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
          <?php $TwoCountry = false ; if(count($aCountries) > 1 ) { $TwoCountry = true ; ?>
          <div class="item-post-country">
            <label class="control-label" for="country">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Country', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::country_select(osc_get_countries()); ?>
          </div>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="countryId" id="countryId" value="<?php echo ctg_country_id(); ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="item-post-province">
            <label class="control-label" for="region">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Province', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions()); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="item-post-region">
            <label class="control-label" for="city">
              <span class="required_fields">* </span>
              <?php _e('Region', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::city_select(osc_get_cities()); ?>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2>
             <strong><?php _e("Publisher Information", 'ctg_housing'); ?></strong>
          </h2>
          <div class="item-post-user-name item-post-columns">
            <label class="control-label" for="contactName">
              <span class="required_fields">*</span>
              <?php _e('Name', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::contact_name_text(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="item-post-user-email item-post-columns">
            <label class="control-label" for="contactEmail">
              <span class="required_fields">*</span>
              <?php _e('E-mail', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
            </label>
            <?php ItemForm::contact_email_text(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div id="submit-button" class="item-post-button text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="small button_radius">
              <?php if($edit) { _e("Update Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } else { _e("Publish Listing", 'ctg_housing'); } ?>
            </button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php } ?>
```